# Setear condicionalmente propiedad de objeto JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema con JavaScrip, simplificando, si pongo el siguiente script en la consola del navegador:

```
const existObjectKey = (obj, key) => {
    return (obj[key] !== undefined);
}

const obj   = {};
const xxx = (id) => {
    const key = 'swap-color-' + id;
    if (! existObjectKey(obj, key)) {
        console.log(0);
        obj.key = 1;
    }
}

xxx('a');
xxx('a');
```

Me saca en la consola dos veces el 0.

**¿Porque no existe clave `a` en el objeto `obj` después de la primera llamada `xxx('a')` y como puedo solucionarlo?**

Comment: necesitas una salida de tipo {swap-color-a: 1} ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la notación de [miembros](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Miembros) para *setear* la propiedad, agregue unos `console.log()` en el código para que veas

```js
const existObjectKey = (obj, key) => {
    return (obj[key] !== undefined);
}

const obj = {};
const xxx = (id) => {
    const key = 'swap-color-' + id;
    if (! existObjectKey(obj, key)) {
        
        obj[key] = 1;
        console.log(`se agrego ${key} en el obj`)
    }else{
      console.log(`ya existe ${key} en el obj`)
    }
}


xxx('red');
xxx('red');
console.log(obj)
```

### ¿Porque no funciona con la notación de punto?

```js
const obj = {
  
}

const setearPropiedad = (prop,ob)=>{
  ob.prop='seteado'

  // va a setear la clave 'prop literalmente sin no va a tener 
  // el valor de propPARAMETRO'
}

const setearPropiedad2 = (prop,ob)=>{
  ob[prop]='seteado'

  // La notacion de corchetes puede obtener el acceso a 
  // las propiedades mediante variables tambien cuando la propiedad
  // tiene caracteres especiales
}

setearPropiedad ( 'key', obj)
console.log(obj)

setearPropiedad2 ( 'key', obj)
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Funciona, sabía que era alguna tontería... ¿Sabes por qué no funciona la *notación por puntos*?

Comment: ahi la edite con la respuesta